# Gradle miss environment variable when running tasks from IntelliJ IDA in WSL

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a Gradle project with multiple sub modules. Some of these are using maven. Thus one Gradle task is running maven from the MAVEN_HOME directory. This task is called by IntelliJ IDEA during Gradle refresh. When running IntelliJ Community Edition 2021.1 on an Ubuntu 20_05 VM, everything works fine. When running the same version of IntelliJ Windows with WSL 2, the task fails with error

```
    MAVEN_HOME environment variable not set, unable to locate mvn executable for build
```

When I open a shell in WSL, I see that the MAVEN_HOME is actually set. I've defined it in my `~/.profile` file. I can build my project from the terminal command line. IntelliJ IDEA uses the Gradle wrapper for building the project. It uses the shebang `#!/bin/env sh`. So it is not opening a login shell und thus the ~/.profile files are not read.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec /bin/bash -i -l -c env`